# Ag-grid grouping: avoid changing the order in which groups are displayed after editing

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

When I inline edit a group title, the whole group gets moved to the bottom of the table. How can I avoid this from happening and maintain the initial order?

How it looks like when the page first load:

[image: How it looks like when the page first load]

How it looks like once I edit the title of the first group:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when I update the group title, the grid does a delta change and adds one more row to represent this group while not touching the DOM with the remaining rows.

There is a property in `gridOptions` called `deltaRowDataMode` that is set to `true` by default. Setting it to `false` solves the problem. Bear in mind that if you have a table displaying a large number of rows, this solution could decrement performance.

NOTE: as of today's date, there is nothing in the ag-grid documentation explaining about `deltaRowDataMode` or an in-depth explanation about the delta change.

Comment: somehow it is missing in the latest docs, you can find it here - https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/23.0.2/javascript-grid-data-update/#delta-row-data